# C# Native Mobile App - Cannot Compile Existing Xamarin Project to DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

[Background]

I'm fairly new to C# development in general - I did some messing around in my early years, but nothing too in-depth. For a project, a teammate and I are developing a mobile exercise game which uses a step counter. Rather than reinvent the wheel, we found an open source step counter project from GitHub which we would like to use (https://github.com/MikeCodesDotNet/My-StepCounter).

[Problem]

For our project, we would like to use the step counter services available in that project. However, when I try to build them to a DLL, I get the following errors:

```
BootReceiver.cs(20,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
StepService.cs(21,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
StepService.cs(25,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'StepCounter' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

And so on and so forth. It doesn't seem to be recognizing the Android library. Ideally, what I would like to do is to get the entire project **except for the activities** as a DLL. How do I go about this?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to mix Android specific APIs to be "PCL Compatible" which they are not because they are platform specific.

Comment: are you porting them to an Android library, or a generic .NET library, a PCL, etc?

Comment: @JonDouglas I'd like to do something akin to putting them into a Java jar, i.e. making each csproj into a DLL that I can reference. I'm very new to this, so I'm not even sure if that's possible, and am looking for any alternative which can let me use this cross-platform code. At the moment, my only recourse seems to be copy-pasting, but I really don't want to do that.

Comment: You can create Android Library projects for that reason then. However you can't just move Android code into PCL code. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/